# Find node id by name in Umbraco Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco7

I have a site with structure like `Home -> News -> Year -> Month -> Day -> Article` and need a query to find the id of the `Day` folder where the name of the folder matches a specified `Year`, `Month` and `Day`.

For example for 12th May 2003 it would be something like:

```
@something().where("Year.name = 2003").where("Month.name = May").where("Day.name = 12")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your preference, you can construct a query using either the dynamic [DynamicPublishedContent](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/DynamicPublishedContent/) or the strongly-typed [IPublishedContent](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/IPublishedContent/) API.

The query will be different depending on where it's used, so assuming you want to run this query and display the results in the "News" page, you need something like the following:

```
var year = CurrentPage.Years.Where("Name == @1", "2013").First();
var month = year.Months.Where("Name == @1", "May").First();
var day = month.Days.Where("Name == @1", "12").First();
var dayId = day.Id;
```

Alternatively, you can try the strongly typed version:

```
var day = Model.Content
               .Descendants("Year").First(y => y.Name == "2013")
               .Descendants("Month").First(m => m.Name == "May")
               .Descendants("Day").First(d => d.Name == "12").Id;
```

I've used `First()` for brevity but in reality you might want to check if the page exists before getting its descendants. Also, you might want to have a look at the [documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/) and come up with a query that's better suited to your scenario.

Comment: thank you - please can you direct me where I would find documentation on checking if page exists prior to querying. All methods I found rely on knowing the node id beforehand.

Comment: You could just replace the `First()` statement in the end of your query with `FirstOrDefault()` and check if the result is null.